# Concentration of volume towards the boundary

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, geometric-measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Consider a Euclidean space $X$ of large dimension $N$. For a measurable subset $G\subseteq X$ and $\varepsilon>0$ let
$$G_\varepsilon:=\{x\in G\mid B_\varepsilon(x)\subseteq G\}$$
be the set of all points in $G$ with distance at least $\varepsilon$ from the boundary of $G$.

I am looking for results of the form
$$\mathrm{Vol}(G_\varepsilon)/\mathrm{Vol}(G)\leq \exp(-N\rho(\varepsilon))$$
for bounded measurable sets (or similar results).
This is to make precise the intuition that, as the dimension of the space increases a larger fraction of the volume of a set is concentrated near the boundary.

For example let $G=[0-\varepsilon,1+\varepsilon]^N$, then
$G_\varepsilon=[0,1]^N$ and the volume fraction above becomes $(1+2\varepsilon)^{-N}$ hence the conjecture for exponential decrease.

Are there any results available already?

Comment: For convex bodies this should follow from the isoperimetric inequality. For non-convex, the notion of the Minkowski content might help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\newcommand\ep\varepsilon\newcommand\R{\mathbb R}$Suppose that $G$ is a measurable subset of $\R^N$ with volume $|G|>0$ such that
$$|G|\le C^N|B|,$$
where $C>0$ is a real constant and $B$ is the unit ball in $\R^N$.

Without loss of generality (wlog), $|G_\ep|>0$. Also, $G_\ep+\ep B\subseteq G$ for any real $\ep>0$. So, in view of the [Brunn--Minkowski inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brunn%E2%80%93Minkowski_theorem#Statement),
$$|G|\ge|G_\ep+\ep B|\ge(|G_\ep|^{1/N}+\ep|B|^{1/N})^N
=|G_\ep|\Big(1+\ep\Big(\frac{|B|}{|G_\ep|}\Big)^{1/N}\Big)^N
\ge|G_\ep|\Big(1+\ep\Big(\frac{|B|}{|G|}\Big)^{1/N}\Big)^N
\ge|G_\ep|\Big(1+\frac\ep C\Big)^N.
$$
Thus,
$$\frac{|G_\ep|}{|G|}\le e^{-N\rho(\ep)},\tag{1}\label{1}$$
where $\rho(\ep):=\ln(1+\frac\ep C)$.

---

Here is another (better?) statement:

Suppose that $|G|>0$ and the values of the (outer) measure of the projections of $G$ onto the $N$ coordinate axes of $\R^N$ are no greater than positive numbers $L_1,\dots,L_N$, respectively. Then
$$\frac{|G_\ep|}{|G|}\le\prod_{i=1}^N(1-2\ep/L_i)_+,$$
where $u_+:=\max(0,u)$.

For $N=1$, this follows almost immediately from the definition of the outer measure. For $N>1$, this follows by induction, using one-dimensional cross-sections and the Tonelli theorem.

In particular, if $L_i=L>0$ for all $i$, then
$$\frac{|G_\ep|}{|G|}\le(1-2\ep/L)_+^N\le e^{-2N\ep/L}. \tag{2}\label{2}$$

A further improvement can be obtained by replacing $L_i$, for each $i$, by an upper bound on the measures of all one-dimensional cross-sections of $G$ in the direction of the $i$th coordinate axis.

By considering $G=CB$ and $G=[0,L]^N$, it is clear that the bounds in \eqref{1} and \eqref{2} are optimal, each in its own way.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It uses a function $\rho(\epsilon)$ which depends both on N and the set G. But if you allow such a dependence, it becomes trivial. Now your answer is not trivial because the dependence on N can easily be gotten rid of (and is in the second version).

Comment: I thought it was clear in my question that  $\rho(\epsilon)$ is not allowed to depend on either N or G. The dependence on G makes the statement uninteresting.

Comment: @nullptr : In your post, your say "bounded". This quality needs to be quantified somehow, which was done in my answer. More directly, it should be clear that one cannot get rid of the dependence of $\rho(\epsilon)$ on $G$ -- for instance, take $G=[0,L\}^N$ for large $L$. In fact, the latter bound in my answer is optimal, as is now made explicit.

Comment: Yes, thanks. That settles it.